# How to show that $\nabla \|x\|=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$, $ 0\neq x\in\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, optimization

How to show that $\nabla \|x\|=\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}$, $ 0\neq x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

I can't use the partial differentiation since I don't know if it is differentiable, I have to use the definition, i. e. $$\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}\cdot y+o(y).$$

$o(y)$ is a function such that $$\lim\limits_{\|y\|\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\|o(y)\|}{\|y\|}=0.$$

Using this I find that $$o(y)=\|x+y\|-\|x\|-\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}\cdot y$$

so just left to show that $$\lim\limits_{\|y\|\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\left\|\|x+y\|-\|x\|-\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}\cdot y\right\|}{\|y\|}=0.$$

Comment: I assume you are in $\mathbb{R^n}$.  Then you can use partial differentiation.  Write out $ ||x|| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$.

Comment: How can I use that if there are function that have partial derivatives but they are not differentiable?

Comment: Note that $||x||^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$ is differentiable, thus $||x|| = \sqrt{||x||^2}$ is differentiable away from $0$ and so you can using partial differentiation.

Comment: You should use \|x\| for $\|x\|$ instead of ||x|| to get $||x||$ because the spacing looks better.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that $\nabla x^{T}x=2x$ (Because $x^{T}x=\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k^2$) and derive both sides of the equation $\|x\|^2=x^{T}x$. One gets:

$$2\|x\|\nabla{\|x\|}=2x$$

And this gives for $x\neq 0$

$$\nabla\|x\|={x\over \|x\|}$$

Answer (score 0):

The $k$-th component of the gradient is
$$
\partial_k \lVert x \rVert = 
\partial_k \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} =
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}}2x_i \delta_{ik} =
\frac{x_k}{\lVert x\rVert}
$$
where $\partial_k = \partial/\partial x_k$ and $\delta_{ik}$ is the Kronecker delta for index values $i$ and $k$, which vanishes if the index values $i$ and $j$ differ, otherwise it is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f: x \mapsto ||x||$ on $\mathbb{R^{n}};$ let $(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus \{ 0\}$; and let $x := (x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}).$
Then
$$\nabla f(x) = \big( D_{1}f(x), \dots, D_{n}f(x) \big) = \big( \frac{1}{2}(\sum_{1}^{n}x_{i}^{2})^{-1/2}2x_{1}, \dots, \frac{1}{2}(\sum_{1}^{n}x_{i}^{2})^{-1/2}2x_{n}\big) = (\sum_{1}^{n}x_{i}^{2})^{-1/2}(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}) = \frac{x}{||x||}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$i) f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)=\|x\|^2$ is differentiable and $\nabla f(x)=2x$.

$ii)g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is differentiable at $x\neq 0$ and $g'(x)=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$.

$iii)$ If $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are both diferentiable at $x$ then $g\circ f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $x$ and $\nabla(g\circ f)(x)=g'(f(x))\nabla f(x)$.

Then $\nabla\|x\|=\nabla(g\circ f)(x)=g'(f(x))\nabla f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\|x\|^2}}2x=\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}$ for $x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note
$$ \lim_{t\to0}\frac{\|x+th\|-\|x\|}{t}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\|x+th\|^2-\|x\|^2}{t(\|x+th\|+\|x\|)}=\frac{(x,h)}{\|x\|}$$
namely
$$ \nabla\|x\|(h)=\frac{1}{\|x\|}(x,h). $$
So
$$ \nabla\|x\|=\frac{x}{\|x\|}. $$